# How to make an XML element a blueprint to allow for re-usability?

Tags: android, xml, layout

My XML file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rants_list_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I then have a res/layout/sonich.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sonich"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

My goal is to make the above TextView a reusable view, that is, reference it in the application multiple times to create text views of the properties specified in the above text view.

Hence, in the main activity, I do the following:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rants_list_linear_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sonich);
        linearLayout.addView(txt);
    }
```

This, however, produces the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a
>   ViewGroup

This suggests that the findViewById() method returns a null reference. I do not understand why, since the text view is well defined in the xml file and the findViewById() method works well for the linear layout a few lines before that.

If I change the code to:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rants_list_linear_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText("TextView");
        txt.setTextSize(32);
        linearLayout.addView(txt);
    }
```

everything works fine. However, this is not what I want. I would like to outsource as much code to the xml files as possible. After all, the xml files exist to provide an organised way of specifying layouts, views etc. and their properties, whereas Java code is the one dealing with the app's functionality.

Could you please explain what this error stems from and how to create text views (or any views) programmatically, while referencing xml files to infer the views' properties?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: @kris larson This assumes that the entire app layout is known from the beginning, without discussing the addition of those views programmatically. I am looking for info on how to add views programmatically, without having to specify their attributes programmatically by referencing an xml blueprint containing all of those properties each time I add the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rants_list_linear_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(linearLayout.getContext());
    for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
        View sonich = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sonich, linearLayout, false);
        TextView txt = (TextView) sonich.findViewById(R.id.sonich);
//      Now you don't need to do these since the XML takes care of it
//      txt.setText("TextView");
//      txt.setTextSize(32);
        linearLayout.addView(txt);
    }
```

Comment: I think the sonich.findViewById(R.id.sonich) should be cast to TextView. Also, the setText() and setTextSize() methods are no longer needed since those are specified in the xml files. Other than that, thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: Forgot the cast, updating answer.